# Is this a possible bug in SDCC?

Tags: sdcc

The following code works as expected when compiled with gcc, however when compiled with sdcc (4.2.0) the conditional test `(x2 + y2 >= 800)` doesn't ever appear to be evaluated as true (as only spaces are printed).

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
   const char* a[8] = {"\x1b[0m", "\x1b[0;41m", "\x1b[0;42m", "\x1b[0;43m", 
      "\x1b[0;44m", "\x1b[0;45m", "\x1b[0;46m", "\x1b[0;47m"};
   
   int x, y;
   int x2, y2, x0, y0, i, n;
   char c;

   int xa = -500;
   int xb = 300;
   int ya = 240;
   int yb = -250;
   int xd = 7;
   int yd= 15;
   int m = 20;
   
   y0 = ya;
   while (y0 > yb)
   {
      x0 = xa;
      while (x0 < xb)
      {
         y = 0;
         x = 0;
         c = ' ';
         n = 0;
         i = 0;
         while (i < m)
         {
            x2 = (x * x) / 200;
            y2 = (y * y) / 200;
            if ((x2 + y2) >= 800)
            {
               if (i > 9) c = '0'; else c = '0' + i;
               if (i > 7) n = 7; else n = i;
               i = m;
            }
            y = (x * y / 100 + y0);
            x = (x2 - y2 + x0);
            /* if ((x > 16383) || (y > 16383)) printf(" %d %d ", x ,y); */
            i++;
         }
         printf("%s%c", a[n], c);
         x0 = x0 + xd;
      }
      printf("%s\n", a[0]);
      y0 = y0 - yd;
   }
}
```

This behaviour is consistent when using sdcc (4.2.0) on Debian (bookworm) and sdcc 4.0.0 on Debian(bulseye).

```
$ sdcc -mz80 --no-std-crt0 --data-loc 0 sdc-crt0-args.rel sdc-cpm.rel sdc-mandlebrot.c 
$ sdobjcopy -Iihex -Obinary --gap-fill 0 sdc-mandlebrot.ihx sdc-mandlebrot.com
```

However if I change `int x, y;` to `long x, y;` it works, even though neither `x` or `y` ever exceed 16K.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug with sdcc?

Comment: I've found and reported about a dozen bugs in SDCC, so it could be a bug, yes.  If you can just look at the assembly and tell that the test was miscompiled, that would be good.  If not, you should probably simplify the code as much as possible and make sure you aren't using any undefined behavior.

Comment: @DavidGrayson No, it's not a bug in SDCC. It's in the OP's code.

Comment: You may consider using `uint32_t` from `stdint.h` instead to make sure your code is portable betwen your pc and sdcc.

Comment: @KamilCuk To replace `int` as implemented in SDCC, it should be `int16_t`. Then the PC will show the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDCC uses 16 bits for an `int`, that much you found out. However, you have an overflow in your code.

This is the relevant excerpt, all variables are `int`:

```c
            x2 = (x * x) / 200;
            y2 = (y * y) / 200;
            if ((x2 + y2) >= 800)
```

Because of the products being actually squares, `x2` and `y2` can never be negative.

To get a sum of at least 800, we can differentiate these corner cases:

1. `x2` is 800 or more, `y2` is 0.
2. `x2` is 0, `y2` is 800 or more.
3. `x2` is 400 or more, `y2` is 400 or more.

For any of `x2` or `y2` to be 400 or more, the square of `x` or `y`, respectively, needs to be 400 * 200 = 80000 or more.

This is clearly more than an `int` can represent. The highest value is 32767, divided by 200 will result in 163. So the maximum of `x2 + y2` is 2 * 163 = 326.

---

Why does it work, if you declare `x` and `y` as `long`?

Well, by integer promotion the squares are `long`, too, and the quotient will be correct. The assignments to `x2` and `y2` silently cast down to `int`, but the result is small enough.

This gives a hint how to have an intermediate square in `long`. For this, at least one of the operands needs to be long. But to make it crystal clear to future readers, use explicit casts instead of implicit casts, and don't forget the constants.

```c
            x2 = (int)(((long)x * (long)x) / 200L);
            y2 = (int)(((long)y * (long)y) / 200L);
```

Pro-tip: These expressions look ugly. You might want to try the compiler's optimization capability to inline. For this, define a local helper function. You might want to comment the function extensively.

```c
static int scaled_square(int value) {
    return (int)(((long)value * (long)value) / 200L);
}

/* ... */

            x2 = scaled_square(x);
            y2 = scaled_square(y);
```

---

Final note: While SDCC is a project driven by voluntaries, and *may* therefore have some bugs, it is a matured system built by experienced developers. So *this case* is not a bug in SDCC, but a bug in your code.

I found some compiler bugs in my career, even in expensive and validated closed source compilers, but only every so many years. The vast majority of bugs were my own, more than 99,99%. So I never assume a compiler bug, if something does not work as expected, but always a user bug. You should develop that mind set, too.

Only if you can *prove* by the generated assembly code, you can point to the compiler.

Comment: Your characterization of SDCC as "matured" is incorrect.  I've written basically two projects in it with probably less than 10k lines of code each, and in each of them I found multiple bugs, including bugs resulting in silent incorrect code generation.  Latest examples: [3504](https://sourceforge.net/p/sdcc/bugs/3504/), [2263](https://sourceforge.net/p/sdcc/bugs/2263/) [2431](https://sourceforge.net/p/sdcc/bugs/2431/).  If we take your "99.99%" seriously, then you're saying I had 30,000 total bugs in my projects (nope!).  The SDCC devs at least are responsive and fix the bugs.

Comment: @DavidGrayson These are 3 bugs in nearly 10 years. :-D Did you count the bugs you encountered in corporate software, Adobe, Office, ERP, Windows? -- Yes, if you program since ten years, you had 30,000 bugs. Most of them are revealed by an IDE or a compiler warning or error and you corrected them in a minute. I'm working in safety-related systems, and a human loaded optimally (not bored, not overwhelmed, not tired) has a hazard failure rate of 1 error per 1000 hours. And these are just the hazardous ones.

Comment: Thost 3 bugs were not from 10 years of compiling SDCC code, it was just a sampling of what I found after developing about 20k lines, which isn't much.  We're talking about compilers here and how often they cause bugs in the code they compile, we are not talking about every piece of software one uses in their life.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Concerning the 10 years, I just looked in the linked tickets... ("_Latest examples: ..._") :-D -- A bug in a compiler is not different from a bug in an office application. Both are software I use, and what I do with them results in something I did not expect. And a discrepancy between the expectation and the result is a bug. -- Even after 40+ years in software development, I'm not perfect. But we are discussing opinions, let's stop that. It does not help anyone reading here.

Comment: Very interesting - should I be able to force the result of ```x * x``` to be long using ```(long)(x * x)``` with ```x``` still being an ```int```   ?  (That does not seem to work).

Comment: @the busybee - Thanks your edit is very informative